# Has Visual Studio 2011 Beta been renamed as VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio

Or is VS2012 a totally different version coming out later?

Comment: I think this was a good question. I was getting ready to post the same thing. This absolutely is a real question. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually Visual Studio 11 has been renamed to Visual Studio 2012. There was never such a thing as Visual Studio 2011.